# Why don't non-existent IBOutlets crash the application?

Tags: crash, iboutlet

Sorry if this has been answered before, but I didn't find anything after searching some time.
I'm used to that invoking methods of non-existent objcets leads to a crash.
However, when I have some IBOutlets declared which have no connections to real objects at a xib, I can though send them messages without the event of a crash.
What happens exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of the cocoa runtime you are using several things could happen:

IBOutlet will send a message, but since the reciever(NIL?) does not understand it an exception is thrown, but is caught the console likely prints a message to inform you of this.

IBOutlet first checks `[object respondsTo:@SEL(selector)]`, if false it does nothing.

The XIB object does not invoke your message delegate message (getter) at all, because it is not intersted in it.